spatie-backup to run on WAMP
I cannot configure laravel 10 spatie 9.3 to work on my local installation using anything else than the terminal (e.g. using it  via controller  / blade file...)
iam running WAMP , PHP8.2;Mysql8.2 and laravel 10
I have made changes to the config/backup.php introducing the following array fields:
'databases' => [
                'mysql',
            ],
            'db_dump' => [
                'mysql' => [
                    'dump_binary_path' => env('MYSQL_DUMP_PATH'),
                    'use_single_transaction' => true,
                    'timeout' => 60* 5,

                ],
            ],

with:MYSQL_DUMP_PATH=C:/wamp64/bin/mysql/mysql8.2.0/bin/mysqldump.exe
or directly defining the dump-binary-path within the earlier mysql definiton...
and then calling either :
Artisan::call('backup:run');

or the shell command
